# jQuery 3.2.1 Modal with MVC Partial View

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I'm trying to use a modal to submit a form derived from an MVC partial view.  The form in the partial view works independently, but when I'm having trouble getting the modal piece to work.

Includes:

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

The modal in my main view:

```
    <div class="modal hide fade in edit-redirect-modal" id="editModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Edit Redirect</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                Loading...
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The script in my main view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.editRedirect').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.edit-redirect-modal').modal('show').find('.modal-body').load($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

An example link of class "editRedirect":

```
<a href="/Admin/Edit/8154" class="editRedirect" data-target="editModal" data-toggle="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a>
```

When I click the link, the screen darkens, but the modal does not appear.  The console throws this error:

```
> Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #
at Function.Sizzle.error (jquery-3.2.1.js:1580)
at Sizzle.tokenize (jquery-3.2.1.js:2232)
at Sizzle.select (jquery-3.2.1.js:2659)
at Function.Sizzle [as find] (jquery-3.2.1.js:884)
at jQuery.fn.init.find (jquery-3.2.1.js:2922)
at jQuery.fn.init (jquery-3.2.1.js:3032)
at jQuery (jquery-3.2.1.js:98)
at getParent (bootstrap.js:798)
at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (bootstrap.js:782)
at Function.each (jquery-3.2.1.js:362)
```

**UPDATE:** I changed my modal and script to this, and no longer get any console errors, but clicking the link still darkens the page with no dialog content.

```
    <div class="modal fade edit-redirect-modal" id="editModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Edit Redirect</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                Loading...
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var dialog = $("#editModal").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 400,
            width: 350,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                Cancel: function () {
                    dialog.dialog("close");
                }
            },
            close: function () {

            }
        });

        $('.editRedirect').on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#editModal').modal('show').find('.modal-body').load($(this).attr('href'));
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using this method with usable results, although there's a bug where closing the modal and selecting another item re-opens the modal with the previous data.

Anchor:

```
<a href="/Admin/Edit/@item.Id" class="editRedirect" data-target="editModal" data-toggle="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a>&nbsp;
```

Div:

```
<div id="editDialog" title="Edit Redirect" style="display:none;">
<div id="editModal"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(".editRedirect").click(function () {
        $("#editModal").parent('div').load($(this).attr("href"));
        $("#editDialog").dialog({
            width: 400,
            height: 450,
            modal: true
        });

        return false;
```